# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating. CoreSpotlight

Tags: ios, swift2, uistoryboardsegue, corespotlight

I integrate `CoreSpotlight` in my app. I want that user will find need information in spotlight search and after user will open this information in spotlight information opens in `DetailViewController`. I made it, spotlight works nice, but when application is opening I see this error **Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (UIAlertController: 0x1245a0560)**  although I don't use `UIAlertController`. I made in AppDelegate func which call function of UITableViewController which must to open object by index. But it is not appear. Still there is an error in showData()              `performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: nil)`**reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'show''**. Although I add segue ( with show name) and it works when I usually select cell. Please help me.

```
    AppDelegate
  func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
            if let identifier = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
                print(identifier)
                checkWord = identifier // checkWord is String

                let tableC = TableViewController()
                tableC.showData()

                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }


  func showData() {
    let matchString = appDel.checkWord
    if mainArray.contains(matchString) {
        let ind = mainArray.indexOf(matchString)!

        let indexPathMain = NSIndexPath(forItem: ind, inSection: 0)
        print(indexPathMain)
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPathMain, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: nil)
        print("Show data")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't implement willContinueUserActivityWithType or if it returns false, it means that iOS should handle activity. And in this case it can show UIAlertController. So to get rid this warning return true for your activity in this delegate call:

`func application(application: UIApplication,
   willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {
      return true
}`